# Uniform electric field. Find the flux of this field through a square side of 20 cm, parallel to the $y$-$z$ plane?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

A uniform electric field has: $$\bar{E} = 2 \times 10^3 \ \hat{i} \ \  \mathrm{N/C}$$.

Find the flux of this field through a square side 20 cm, whose plane is parallel to the $y$-$z$?

I'm fairly new to the realm of electricity and electrostatics, and would appreciate some advice on, how I should think when tackled with problems pertinent to this topic.

Here's what I tried doing to solve this problem:

$$\bar{\Phi} = \oint \bar{E} \cdot d \bar{S}$$

Therefore, I considered both faces of the square, on the side facing the $\hat{i}$ direction, the flux would be

$$\Phi = \oint E \ dS \ cos \ 0 = E \oint dS $$

On the side facing the $-\hat{i}$ direction, the flux would be:

$$\Phi = \oint E \ dS \ cos \ \pi \ ,$$

since, the area vector and Electric field are in opposite directions

$$\Phi = - E \oint dS \ .$$

Then, I got the net flux as the sum of these, which came out to be 0.

In many of the solutions I've encountered, they only considered one face of the cube, but not both; Why?

Comment: Because flux through the given surface means $\int$ not $\oint$.

Comment: It's your last step, the addition, that's wrong. You can regard the flux as positive in the $\mathbf i$ direction OR as negative in the  $-\mathbf i$ direction.

Comment: @PhilipWood Could you expand on that and elaborate further?

Comment: Suppose that you wanted the flux of water flowing through a cross-section of a pipe running north-south. You calculate that it is 0.40 $\text{m}^3 \text{s}^{-1}$ northwards. You could, alternatively, say that it is –0.40 $\text{m}^3 \text{s}^{-1} $ southwards. But you wouldn't then conclude that the flux is zero, would you? Note that we're dealing only with one cross-section of the pipe, not a length of pipe, just as, I'm assuming, you're dealing with a single square, not two opposite walls of a cube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're interested in the flux through the square not the flux through some cube. You are actually correct in that the flux of this specific electric field through a cube would always be zero (this is actually a consequence of Gauss law for future reference). This is because the flux that goes into the cube goes out of the cube on the other side.

However, you are only interested in the flux through a square, i.e. through one surface, so it suffices to use only the first term:
\begin{equation}
\Phi = \int \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{S} = \int E \,\mathrm{d}S = \int_0^{20 \, \mathrm{cm}} \mathrm{d}y \int_0^{20 \, \mathrm{cm}} \mathrm{d}z \; 2 \times 10^3 \, \mathrm{N/C} = (20 \, \mathrm{cm})^2 \cdot 2 \times 10^3 \, \mathrm{N/C}
\end{equation}

Notice in particular that, as other commenters have noted already, you're not supposed to use the $\oint$ symbol here, but just $\int$. The $\oint$ symbol is only used when integrating over closed surfaces, e.g. a cube or a ball. But a simple square is not a closed surface.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of flux describes how much of something (in this case, electric field lines) passes through an area.

The equation for electric flux through an area is
$$\Phi=E.A=EAcos\theta$$

It can also be defined for a closed surface where the equation is
$$\Phi=\oint E.dA=\frac{q}{\epsilon}$$
where q is the charge enclosed within the closed surface.

If the lines are directed into the surface (entering), flux is taken as negative ($\theta=180$).

If the lines are directed out of the surface (leaving), flux is taken as positive ($\theta=0$).

In your question, it is mentioned that the square of side 20cm is parallel to the $y$$z$ plane. This means that you need only consider the flux through that square surface. So the answer would be
$$\Phi=E.A=2×10^3×20×10^{-2}×20×10^{-2}$$
$$\Phi=80 Vm $$

If they had asked for the flux through a cube, then the net flux would be zero as the number of field lines entering and leaving would be the same (for the sides parallel to $y$$z$ plane).
$$\Phi=-EA+EA=0$$

In case of all the other sides, the $\theta=90$ and so $\Phi=0$